# druid kafka indexing service setup

Tags: json, apache-kafka, druid

I followed the docs and edited:

```
druid-0.9.2/conf/druid/_common/common.runtime.properties
```

and added:

```
"druid-kafka-indexing-service"
```

to the `druid.extensions.loadList` and restarted all druid services: `middlemanager`, `overlord`, `coordinator`, `broker`, `historical`

I ran:

```
curl -X 'POST' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d @kafka_connect/script.json druid_server:8090/druid/indexer/v1/task
```

but got:

```
{"error":"Could not resolve type id 'kafka' into a subtype of [simple type, class io.druid.indexing.common.task.Task]\n at [Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@4c467f1c; line: 1, column: 4]"}
```

The input json has:

```
{
  "type": "kafka",
  "dataSchema": {
    "dataSource": "sensors-kafka",
    "parser": {
      "type": "string",
      "parseSpec": {
        "format": "json",
        "timestampSpec": {
          "column": "timestamp",
          "format": "auto"
        },
        "dimensionsSpec": {
          "dimensions": ["machine", "key"],
          "dimensionExclusions": [
            "timestamp",
            "value"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "metricsSpec": [
      {
        "name": "count",
        "type": "count"
      },
      {
        "name": "value_sum",
        "fieldName": "value",
        "type": "doubleSum"
      },
      {
        "name": "value_min",
        "fieldName": "value",
        "type": "doubleMin"
      },
      {
        "name": "value_max",
        "fieldName": "value",
        "type": "doubleMax"
      }
    ],
    "granularitySpec": {
      "type": "uniform",
      "segmentGranularity": "HOUR",
      "queryGranularity": "NONE"
    }
  },
  "tuningConfig": {
    "type": "kafka",
    "maxRowsPerSegment": 5000000
  },
  "ioConfig": {
    "topic": "sensor",
    "consumerProperties": {
      "bootstrap.servers": "kafka_server:2181"
    },
    "taskCount": 1,
    "replicas": 1,
    "taskDuration": "PT1H"
  }
}
```

Any idea what I did wrong? According to the doc:
`http://druid.io/docs/0.9.2-rc3/development/extensions-core/kafka-ingestion.html`, the `type` is `kafka`?

Is there a way to check that the extension was loaded properly or do I have to specify the extension in each component's `runtime.properties`?

Answer (score 3):

I meet the similar problems,and I fixed it by modify the file of "conf/druid/_common/common.runtime.properties" by add "druid-kafka-indexing-service" to druid.extensions.loadList,and now its show like this:

```
druid.extensions.loadList=["druid-parser-route", "mysql-metadata-storage", "druid-kafka-indexing-service"]
```

Hope can help anyone else

Answer (score 2):

The supervisors json specs are to be sent on this endpoint on the overlord `/druid/indexer/v1/supervisor`

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @kafka_connect/script.json http://druid_server:8090/druid/indexer/v1/supervisor
```

Comment: If the error changed to something like Kafka cannot be resolved by overlord, I would double check that extensions are correctly loaded, it is printed at overlord startup

Comment: okay worked it out. I was using the quickstart guide but the extensions documentation refers to `conf` not `conf-quickstart` which I was using the start the services... Now I got an `error 500` instead but that is because the data source has been coded to send out `timestamp` as epoch not `YYYY-MM-DD` etc

Answer (score 0):

if using [dockerized apache/druid](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/druid), you need to set

> druid.extensions.loadList=["druid-histogram", "druid-datasketches",
> "druid-lookups-cached-global", "postgresql-metadata-storage",
> "druid-kafka-indexing-service"]

in file
`/opt/druid/conf/druid/cluster/_common/common.runtime.properties`